# Django Form Fields won't show in my template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

The form field won't show up in the browser. There is only the submit button showing up.

*views.py* code:

```
def vote(request, pk):
    # check if request is post
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form and populate it with data from request
        form = forms.Vote(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fact = Fact.objects.get(pk=pk)
            fact.votes += int(form.cleaned_data['vote'])
            fact.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
                'facts:detail',
                args=(pk,)
            ))
    else:
        form = forms.Vote()
    return render(request, 'facts/fact_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

*template(fact_detail.html)* code:

```
<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="vote" />
</form>
```

*Form class(forms.py)* code:

```
VOTE_CHOICES = [
    (1, 'upvote'),
    (0, 'downvote')
]


class Vote(forms.Form):
    vote = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES,  widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Comment: what is seeing when you print(form) ? are you seeing the form fields ?

Answer (score 0):

In **views.py** for the **vote** method initialize the **form** variable locally, before passing it as a parameter.

```
def vote(request, pk):
     form=""
    //rest of the code//
       return render(request, 'facts/fact_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Try printing form.errors after you call form.is_valid.I doubt you are not getting the data from request.post or it might be invalid.

Comment: When I click the submit(vote) button, this shows up in my terminal:   
`Method Not Allowed (POST): /facts/1/
[10/Oct/2017 13:35:03] "POST /facts/1/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

Comment: Can you please post your URLs.py file

Comment: Here is the vote url which is used for the form`# vote
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),`

Comment: In the httpResponseredirct  you are using  'facts:detail' instead of '/facts_detail/'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend  check generic editing views from django documentation I think it has the solution 
[   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview][1]